# Benchmarking with JIT

Tags: java, benchmarking, jit

A colleague asked me recently about profiling/benchmarking a Java program. Since I am having background in a optimized/compiled programming language, namely Haskell - I was wondering how is it even possible to reliably benchmark jitted programming languages like Java for example?

Wouldn't the just in time compilation interfere and make early samples irrelevant?

And how to know when the JIT has optimized the code "good" enough?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java?rq=1 - Did you check this thread?

Comment: Seriously, who started calling it 'JAVA'? It's so annoying. _Please_, use the correct 'Java'.

Comment: @user3493289 i did not check it - i will read the paper referenced in the accepted answer